# Set data attribute to div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, jquery-data

I am trying to set a data attribute to a div which previously doesn't have any value.

```
<div></div>
```

with jQuery, the first method (data) doesn't do anything, however the attr method works correctly.

```
var div = $('div');
div.data('superhero_one','batman');
div.attr('data-superhero_two','spiderman');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5bT8p/

Am I using incorrectly the data function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does work !

The actual thing behind that is , you can't see actual attribute when you use `.data()` because jquery sets that internally.
but `.attr()` adds an attribute to the element which you can inspect.

see this demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/5bT8p/1/

Comment: So in order to see it "externally" I can only use attr()?

Comment: @Alvaro Yes. But, Why you would need to see that "externally"

Comment: I am using skrollr, and although it is made to apply data attributes directly in html, I want to control them with javascript before applying init in the plugin. Thanks

Comment: Me too `.data()` is not work, but if I used for `.attr()` it works.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("div").data("superhero_two","spiderman");
```

is the right syntax. But when inspecting, I'm only seeing `data-superhero_two="spiderman"` (as intended). The attribute from `.attr` is set in the DOM, and the `.data`  is set in the **JQuery object only**.

By the way, use the document ready function to ensure its execution at the right time:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").data("superhero_two","spiderman");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div").data("superhero_two","spiderman");
```

I suggest you give [.data() | jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/) a read. You'll find plenty of examples there to set and get data attributes.

Here is an in use example of the same on jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/yrshaikh/293nk/1/

Comment: I gave it a read, and this doesn't do what it should. At least Chrome is not showing the div changed at all. Only using attr()

Comment: As others said, it works as jQuery object,but doesnt reflect it in the DOM. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Is working fine, because they have different behaviours, `jQuery.data`:

> Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements or return
>   the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of
>   matched elements.

so your element will not have any html attribute set, but the key-value pair is stored inside the jQuery object reference.

In short the difference is `$.data` is used for storing information without any alteration on the DOM element, `attr` is used to manipulate attributes of an element.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5bT8p/3/

Comment: Then I misunderstood how it works, I should use attr() to actually apply the data right? Thanks

Comment: It depends, if you want to manipulate DOM attribute use attr (I think is your case), if you want to store data use, data; added in the answer